# Android, gradle, Proguard error while computing stack sizes:

Tags: android, gradle, proguard

After upgrading the support v13 lib and google_play in my project I having an issue with proguard.
I have been searching around, but did not find the solution to this error:

```
 Unexpected error while computing stack sizes:
 Class       = [com/google/android/gms/tagmanager/as]
 Method      = [run()V]
 Exception   = [java.lang.IllegalArgumentException] (Stack size becomes  negative after instruction [35] pop in [com/google/android/gms/tagmanager/as.run()V])
:xxxxx:proguardReleaseclean FAILED
```

The proguard version is 4.7

In the build.gradle:

```
dependencies {
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v13:22.0.+'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:6.5.87'
    compile files('libs/gson-2.2.4.jar')
}
android {
    compileSdkVersion 19
    buildToolsVersion '20.0.0'
}
```

In the proguard Cfg (after added the -dontwarn, for support v4 and gms)

```
-keep class * extends java.util.ListResourceBundle {
    protected Object[][] getContents();
}

-keep public class com.google.android.gms.common.internal.safeparcel.SafeParcelable {
    public static final *** NULL;
}

-keepnames @com.google.android.gms.common.annotation.KeepName class *
-keepclassmembernames class * {
    @com.google.android.gms.common.annotation.KeepName *;
}

-keepnames class * implements android.os.Parcelable {
    public static final ** CREATOR;
}

-dontwarn android.support.v4.**
-dontwarn android.support.v13.**
-dontwarn com.google.android.gms.**

-keep class android.support.v13.app.** { *; }
-keep interface android.support.v13.app.** { *; }
-keep class android.support.v4.app.** { *; }
-keep interface android.support.v4.app.** { *; }
```

I did try lot of things without success.

Any hint would be great !!
Thanks

Comment: I found the reason, in my proguard I also remove all the Log.x( .....) call, and that was causing the failure. Commenting this **-assumenosideeffects class android.util.Log { *; }** in the config the error is gone

Answer (score -2):

try add "-dontoptimize" in progard.

If not work add code as follow:

```
-dontshrink
-dontoptimize
-dontusemixedcaseclassnames
-dontskipnonpubliclibraryclasses
-dontskipnonpubliclibraryclassmembers
-dontpreverify
```

Comment: something similar happened to me and `-dontoptimize` fixed it. thanks!

Comment: It is not a solution. We need optimization by proguard to shrink code, and to remove redundant instructions, as a result it will increace performance of the release build.